# Writing custom view for 404 render 500 Error page

Tags: django, python-3.x, http-status-code-404

I wanted to write a custom view to render my 404. So I defined it like that :

```
class PageNotFoundView(IndexView):
    template_name = 'blogengine/404.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.none

    def get_context_data(self):
        return self.get_context_categories()
```

which derived the IndexView which is

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    def get_context_categories(self):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**self.kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Because I want all the categories in all the pages.

And setted up the urlconf like that in my main urlconf

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from blogengine.views import PageNotFoundView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('blogengine.urls')),
)

handler404 = PageNotFoundView.as_view()
```

In the settings.py I put the hosts I needed :

```
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my.customHost.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1',]
```

But when I deployed it I had an 500 internal error when I tried a bad URL.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

No need for everything, be careful with your definitions, they need to be the same as the originals.

```
class PageNotFoundView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blogengine/404.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageNotFoundView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        except:
            pass
        return context
```

Comment: And what is the traceback?

Comment: Your view gives me this : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/home/juanwolf/Documents/tools/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 118, in __iter__
    raise ContentNotRenderedError('The response content must be '
django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.

Comment: A TemplateView instance must be rendered manually for custom 404 views. Try ```response = TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name, context); response.render(); return response```

Comment: @JuanWolf were you able to fix this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @akshay Yes. I changed my class based view into a function. And in the main urls.py of your project I used : handler404 = "myapp.views.page_not_found_view". Sorry for the late reply BTW